# TYPO3 7.6 frontend editing

Tags: typo3, typoscript, typo3-7.6.x

I have some troubles with frontend editing in TYPO3 7.6

I use the feedit extension which comes with the core.

In the setup.ts I have the following code:

```
config.admPanel = 1
```

which shows me the admin panel.

I created a user group according to the TYPO3 wiki:
https://wiki.typo3.org/Frontend_editing

The usergroup contains the following code in the TSConfig field:

```
 admPanel {
  enable.edit = 1
  module.edit.forceNoPopup = 0
  module.edit.forceDisplayFieldIcons = 1
  module.edit.forceDisplayIcons = 0
  hide = 1
 }
```

The only CE in the FE I can edit is the mailform. All fluid or core CE's can't be edited in the FE.

If I add a mailform in the BE and change the type to e.g. text in the FE the "edit" icon disappears (I've tried all types but only mailform is ok).

Has anyone an idee?

Comment: and in the backend every content type is editable?

Comment: yes it is. I haven't found a solution yet.

Answer (score 0):

Try add for backend user (seem to be 'admin') TSconfig  like:

```
admPanel {
    enable.edit = 1
    enable.cache = 0
    module.edit.forceNoPopup = 0
    module.edit.forceDisplayFieldIcons = 1
    module.edit.forceDisplayIcons = 0
    hide = 1
    override {
    preview{
            showHiddenRecords = 1
            showHiddenPages = 1
        }
        edit {
            displayFieldIcons = 1
            displayIcons = 1
        }
    }
}
```

You can find backend user in website sys_root (id=0 very top) by web module - 'list'. TSconfig on Options tab.

In my case all fluid_styled_contend elements and event EXT:plugins editable. Also pls check you TS mp you have some limitations from this options  https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/ContentObjects/Editpanel/Index.html like "edit.displayRecord".

Answer (score 0):

After SEVERAL hours trying and searching, this is what made the trick for Typo3 7.6.

Consider you are using Bootstrap Package like me.

1. Make sure you have the extensions **feedit** and **fluid_styled_content** active.
2. Go to templates module on the Root page. (In my case pid 1). Edit the whole template record and make sure **Content Elements (fluid_sytled_content)** is loaded **AFTER** bootstrap_package. (If you load it before, it won't work).
3. Create a group for all users that need the frontend editing enabled (In my case I called the group **All Users** and added the users to this group).
4. Add this **TSconfig** to the group you created:

> ```
> admPanel {
>     enable.edit = 1
>     enable.preview = 1 ### Let editor choose to see hidden Pages or hidden Records 
>     enable.cache = 0
>     hide = 1
>     override {
>       preview{
>             showHiddenRecords = 0
>             showHiddenPages = 0
>         }
>         edit {
>             displayFieldIcons = 1
>             displayIcons = 1
>         }
>     }
> }
> ```

5. Go to **Access Module** and apply the group as the group owner you created to the pages you need the FE editing. (In my case all pages - I used the recursive option to apply to all)
6. If it's still not working, check if you TS Setup has this line:

> page.config.admPanel = 1

Now you can enjoy your Frontend Editing :)

Answer (score 0):

After some time of trial and error I figured out that deleting the `hide = 1` did the job in my project....

```
admPanel {
    enable.edit = 1
    enable.preview = 1 ### Let editor choose to see hidden Pages or hidden Records 
    enable.cache = 0
    override {
      preview{
            showHiddenRecords = 0
            showHiddenPages = 0
        }
        edit {
            displayFieldIcons = 1
            displayIcons = 1
        }
    }
}
```